# Amplifier circuit design for ADC: Could input voltage mix with reference voltage?

Tags: operational-amplifier, circuit-analysis, adc, differential-amplifier

This might be a silly question. I saw this from "Opamp For Everyone" and was a bit confused with this circuit. The book doesn't mention the signal source at all, I think it does have a signal input, whose low frequency is filtered by C1 at first. The non-inverting input of the first op-amp has the exact reference voltage buffered by the second op-amp. C3 provides a decoupling effect to suppress current from entering the first op-amp. The first op-amp has a gain of -RF/RG which causes the output to have a magnified input with a 180-degree phase shift if it is by itself with a grounded non-inverting input. Because now the non-inverting input of the first op-amp has the reference voltage, the first op-amp is actually a differential op-amp in this circuit? What is the point for ADC's input if the input is minus by reference voltage?

[image]

Comment: The answer depends on the ADC details.

Comment: There is one possible confusion I can see with **Figure 3.6**: The magnitude of the \$V_{_\text{REF}}\$, which in the figure must be one half of the ADC reference voltage, which with single-supply ADCs is usually taken to be the maximum voltage that they can accept and digitize. This circuit requires the buffered voltage to be half of the maximum. Not the maximum, itself. The text does earlier say *"instead of being equal and opposite +V, it is halfway between +V and ground."* But, unfortunately, they don't make it clear for this figure.

Comment: @periblepsis The reference voltage (DC) is 2.5V, and the power supply of the second op-amp is between 5V and ground (0V). It should be fine for the second op-amp to have Vref at its output by not going to be saturated.

Comment: @TSLee So I do not understand what you are struggling with. In chapter 2 they discuss the case with RF and RG and that opamp. Pretty clearly, I think. The idea of a buffer amplifier is kind of assumed in the text. But it's not hard. And they explain that R1 is necessary (as compared to Figure 3.5.) You appear to know that the Vref should be half what the ADC is using as a reference. So I'm just at a loss, I guess. You seem to already have everything in hand, while saying you don't. I'm mixed up.

Comment: @periblepsis I got confused when it said "It is operating at a positive supply of þV/2 and a negative supply of V/2, with a virtual ground point in between. Because of C1 and C2, it is unaware of the fact that its “ground” is actually þV/2." for the circuit on figure 3.2. I have been trying to catch up with the terminology the book used such as "decouple" and "DC operating point", as this is the first book about electronics I have ever read, except textbooks.

Comment: @periblepsis The book took steps to finalize the circuit, however, I didn't realize some of the components were not for the same use anymore when the circuit was updated. For example, C3 is to decouple in Figure 3.3, but in 3.6 it formed a low pass filter with R1.

Comment: @TSLee Yes, C3 in Figure 3.3 is at an input and is a decoupling cap for a resistor divider reference. This has nothing whatever to do with the C3 placed in Figure 3.6. I suppose a reason you got confused is that the authors point up some possible problems with the idea used in figure 3.3 -- namely that it loses effect near DC and that caps may go inductive at high freq. So then they moved on to a different topology approach.

Comment: @periblepsis Yes, now I realize that. And, I have to study more about capacitors, as I didn't know they would become inductive at a very high frequency. How about "It is operating at a positive supply of V/2 and a negative supply of V/2, with a virtual ground point in between. Because of C1 and C2, it is unaware of the fact that its “ground” is actually +V/2." for the circuit in figure 3.2.? It is a single-supply opamp whose non-inverting input has Vref. I don't understand what that means.

Comment: @TSLee You have a `lot` of questions. (Legit. But this is turning into a discussion, real fast like.) Capacitors really only do one thing, act like imperfect capacitors. But in our minds' eye, we see them playing different roles. Making up ways to think about them helps us. (They don't care.) In figure 3.2 these are used as DC blocking caps, at both ends. They are supposed to allow AC through them but to hard-stop DC. Those are just words, though. The reality is that they charge up (that takes time, too) to the average volt-difference and only ***then*** do they block DC.

Comment: @TSLee In this case, the opamp can be moved around (made to operate at very negative voltages for the most part or to operate at very positive voltages for the most part) but those two caps will, regardless of that aspect of the design, just charge up to whatever difference there is between the input source and the amplifier system (C1) or between the output load and the amplifier system (C2.) So where the amplifier system itself is positioned doesn't really matter because those caps are there and they will automatically adjust to anything you throw at them.

Comment: @TSLee Of course, as I said, they don't do all that starting from the very first picosecond of operation. Rather, when power is applied they take a while to figure out what in the heck the average voltage difference really is. During that time (may be nanoseconds or microseconds or even longer in some cases), they don't perform their DC blocking function very well. So there is short period during which they have to charge up. But once that takes place, they will only slightly discharge and recharge in an equilibrium state around the average. Then they do their DC blocking.

Comment: @TSLee I'm starting to get a better idea of just how much you need to talk with someone. You should look for someone local who can help you out. Seriously. It doesn't take a long time -- I'm sure you are very smart and will follow a discussion and ask good questions along the way. But you need to be able to interrogate the answers you get so that you can copy the useful ideas in someone else's head into your head with some fidelity. Only through conversation and *dialogue* can that happen. And this place rejects that idea, unfortunately.

Comment: @TSLee  A newsgroup like sci.electronics.basics or sci.electronics.design would be better suited.

Comment: @periblepsis Thanks a lot, I will consider your feedback and suggestions. So, the swing between the ground is actually about between C1 and input or C2 and output. I thought it was totally about the opamp and its power supply with its inputs, which didn't make sense at all.

Comment: @TSLee These are all "single-ended" inputs and outputs. This means that one end of them is hidden away where you cannot see it and tied to some (any, actually) voltage source. This could be ground. But it could just as well be +12 V or -5 V. That end, the hidden one, doesn't matter so long as it is tied to a voltage source somewhere. The input you see is the other half of that signal source. That's why it's called single-ended. A differential input would show you ***both*** ends. When you see only one, it is single-ended.

Comment: @TSLee Now, suppose the input source is tied (hidden) to a -12 V rail. So the signal at the input of figure 3.3 will see variations around -12 V on left of cap. Maybe 100 mV around it? Doesn't matter. Let's say that the opamp amplifier stage's input is balanced around +2.5 V, just to pick something. Then the capacitor will automatically charge up to about 14.5 V across it. Now, any signal input near -12 V will have +14.5 V added to it by the capacitor. Only the signal gets through. The DC bias on the cap "jacks up" the negative source so it matches up. It does this all automatically. Nice.

Comment: @periblepsis You are saying that the assumption is that the hidden end of opamp is -12V, and inputs are around 2.5V (closed-loop), so the difference between them is 14.5V, is the value of voltage across the capacitor?

Comment: @TSLee No. Wasn't talking about any part of the opamp being hidden. Just the signal source. But as you can see, the discussion continues. And this is why I'm telling you to find someone local. This is important. You need someone to share their mind with you. The powers that be here won't allow that process to unfold organically. So you need someone local. Or a forum or newsgroup.

Comment: @periblepsis OK, next time I will try to post it here and somewhere else. Could you please just clarify what "the input source is tied (hidden) to a -12 V rail" means? I almost get it. Sometimes when a thing was described in another way, I took longer to understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> this might be a silly question.

not at all

> I think it does have a signal input, whose low frequency is filtered by C1 at first.

Yes, the signal is connected to C1 and this constitutes a high pass filter with RG. But its primary purpose is to AC-couple the input. This way the circuit can arrange its DC biasing without having to take into account some unknown DC voltage from the source.

> The non-inverting input of the second op-amp has the exact reference voltage buffered by the third op amp.

There are only two opamps. It appears you’re calling the top one the 2nd, the bottom one the 3rd. The bottom opamp is buffering the Vref from the ADC.

> C3 provides a decoupling effect to suppress current from entering the second op-amp.

No, the input current of opamps is essentially zero. C3 combines with R1 to form a low pass filter to remove noise from Vref. The bottom opamp was put in so the Vref pins wouldn’t have to drive the RC filter directly.

> The second op-amp has a gain of -RF/RG which causes the output to have a magnified input with a 180-degree phase shift if it is by itself with a grounded non-inverting input.

Yes

> Because now the non-inverting input of the second op-amp has the reference voltage, the second op-amp is actually a differential op-amp in this circuit?

Not really. The voltage of the two opamp inputs will be equal, so the inverting input will be fixed at a DC value of Vref. Because the opamp input draws no current, and C1 blocks any DC current, there is no DC current through RF, so the DC voltage on the other side of RF will be Vref too. The AC signal will be superimposed on that (after it is inverted and multiplied by RF/RIN).

> What is the point for ADC's input if the input is minus by reference voltage?

The ADC input is actually the (inverted and gained) input plus the reference voltage.

Comment: Can't the non-inverting input have Vref directly? Vref is DC voltage. Where does the noise come from?

Comment: How does the ADC handle the superimpose of AC and DC voltage?

Comment: Vref is DC and ideally only DC. But every system has noise and that can manifest as a small AC noise component superimposed on Vref. The RC filter is a cheap way to reduce that – it will attenuate any extraneous AC activity while not affecting the DC component. If Vref has an insignificant amount of noise (likely) then the filter won’t be of any benefit. As for the ADC, it requires the DC component (2.5V) to center the signal into the middle of its 0 to 5V range. If there were no DC bias (i.e. centered around ground) the AC signal would cause excursions below zero which the ADC can’t read.

Comment: Thanks. So, DC bias in this dialogue means voltage reference? As the ADC takes Vref as the reference for the measurement, ADC considers the input as 1 when AC is above this value and 0 when below (Generally, AC signal is sinusoidal). I have this question (How does the ADC handle the superimpose of AC and DC voltage?), because I saw ADC input is separated from Vref in a typical ADC circuit.

Comment: The ADC will render the incoming voltage as a digital value, either signed or unsigned depending on the part. For example, an 8-bit ADC that is set up for signed output will yield 0x00 for a mid-point 2.5V input, and positive inputs will yield 0x01 up to 0x7f, and negative inputs from 0xff down to 0x80. If unsigned, then 2.5V mid point will yield 0x80, pos values from 0x81 up to 0xff and neg values from 0x7f down to 0x00.